# Angular 8 failed deploy to Github Pages -

Tags: angular, deployment, github-pages, angular8, ngx-translate

Everything works fine on my localhost.

Then I used `ng deploy --base-href=/dentist-angular/` to deploy my app to Github Pages.

There is an HTTP error response for each section where my text should be. You should know that all text is being pulled into the page using NGX translate - so I assume this is part of the issue.

I have deleted and redeployed but the problem persists.

Error message in the console...

```
Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "https://jamesross06000.github.io/assets/i18n/fr.json", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for https://jamesross06000.github.io/assets/i18n/fr.json:
```

This could well be a path issue, but as I followed the install and deploy instructions exactly, I'm not sure what to try from here.

HTML...

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Dentist</title>
    <base href="https://jamesRoss06000.github.io/dentist-angular/">    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <script src="env.js"></script>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.748d964c6c80975e08dc.css"></head>
  <body>
    <app-root></app-root>
  <script src="runtime-es2015.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.edb2fcf2778e7bf1d426.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.6696c533341b95a3d617.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.2987770fde9daa1d8a2e.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es2015.c08ed25e5c5c9aef5a4b.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.c08ed25e5c5c9aef5a4b.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

Is it just that using NGX translate with Github Pages is a big no-no?

Here is the Github Pages URL if you needed to see the errors logged in the console.

This is an error that is repeated several times in the console log...

```
ee  @   main-es2015.c08ed25….js:1
```

And this is the file structure within the created dist folder...

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Can you update the file structure?

Comment: Added file structure image to question above

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution, although I don't have an explanation as to why it wasn't working before.

To build and deploy an Angular 8 project to Github pages use the following...

`npm install -g angular-cli-ghpages`

`ng build --prod --base-href "<repo-name>"`

`ngh --dir dist/<project-name>`

The above done the trick for me.